# Will Samsung Pay still work on the Gear S3 if you root your Samsung phone?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-knox, google-pay

Specifically on a Note 5 5.1.1. Knox IS tripped, but I'm hoping I'll still be able to use Samsung pay on the watch since you install it as an applet using the gear app rather than the actual Samsung pay app. I've seen posts saying it works with Samsung pay on non-Samsung phones, but haven't yet found out if it will work in my case with a knox-tripped Samsung phone. Anyone have one that can confirm/deny?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, yes it worked out perfectly! I was able to open Samsung pay thru the gear app and set everything up no problems. As a note, I did unroot via superSU before trying anything, but Knox is still broke of course and I haven't removed any other root artifacts. I also plan on restoring root tomorrow.